# Keras load numpy arrays as filters for weights

Tags: python, numpy, import, theano, keras

I have a model network implemented in keras with theano as the backend which currently initialises with random weights for the filters:

```
# Combine and reshape for convolution
seq = concat(embeddings)
cshape = (config.window_size, sum(f.output_dim for f in features))
seq = Reshape((1,)+cshape)(seq)

# Convolutions
conv_outputs = []
for filter_size, filter_num in zip(config.filter_sizes, config.filter_nums):
    conv = Convolution2D(filter_num, filter_size, cshape[1], activation='relu')(seq)
    cout = Flatten()(conv)
    conv_outputs.append(cout)
seq = concat(conv_outputs)
```

But now I want to be able to load in previously generated weights which were stored as numpy arrays.
This is the altered code which attempts to read in the arrays:

```
# Combine and reshape for convolution
seq = concat(embeddings)
cshape = (config.window_size, sum(f.output_dim for f in features))
seq = Reshape((1,)+cshape)(seq)

# Convolutions
conv_outputs = []
for filter_size, filter_num in zip(config.filter_sizes, config.filter_nums):
    filters = np.load('path/to/filters/size-%d.npy' % filter_size)
    conv = Convolution2D(filter_num, filter_size, cshape[1], weights=filters)(seq)
    cout = Flatten()(conv)
    conv_outputs.append(cout)
seq = concat(conv_outputs)
```

When I try to run the augmented script, I run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conv.py", line 78, in <module>
    weights=filters)(seq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 458, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 324, in build
    self.set_weights(self.initial_weights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 846, in set_weights
    ' weights. Provided weights: ' + str(weights))
Exception: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "convolution2d_1" with a  weight list of length 3, but the layer was expecting 2 weights.
```

I've tried searching online but I can't figure out why keras is throwing this error up.